# SSRS Report suddenly not working

Tags: reporting-services

I have a web portal that calls up reports on my report server.  One report in particular suddenly stopped working this morning from the portal.  I can look at it in Visual Studio and in the Report Manager, but it doesn't work when viewed through the portal.  When I look at the log to see what happened, I see this:

```
The operation you are attempting on item '/' is not allowed for this item type
```

I have made no changes to this report in weeks, so I have no idea what happened, what this error means, or what I can do to fix it.

Comment: Here's a few things you can research and get back to the question with results: updates on the server, event log on the server, ExecutionLog2 in the Reporting DB, running the report on the *exact* same data as on production, download the RDL and compare it to your local version using your version control system, render the report through the SSRS web service straight on production, triple check the calling code for potential problems (especially the way paths are constructed). Good luck!

Comment: No server updates that I am aware of, the only log I have access to is the ReportServerService log, I currently can't get to the ReportingDB, the report is using production data, the RDL isn't in version control yet, we're not using the web service (the report is called via a direct URL link to the server) and there is no calling code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole problem was that I had ItemPath= in my link.  I took that out and it works fine.  Why this thing couldn't have given a better error message, I'll never know.  Wasted a whole day on that one.